# How to wait for React context to load before loading page in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, frontend, react-context

I'm new to React and this is my first time using the Context API.

I'm creating a site with Next.js which would list items added by users similar to an e-commerce website.

I'm currently using useState and Context API to simulate a default list of items that would otherwise be pulled in from a database.

```
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react';

const ItemContext = createContext();

export function useItems() {
    return useContext(ItemContext);
}

export function ItemContextProvider ({ children }) {
    const itemContext = useItemContext();

    return (
        <ItemContext.Provider value={itemContext}>
            {children}
        </ItemContext.Provider>
    )
}

function useItemContext () {
    const [items, setItems] = useState([
        {id: 1, name: 'Apple Earphones', img:'CLOUDINARY_IMAGE_LINK', location: 'location',
        type: 'Electronics', contact: { Phone: '1234567890'},
        used: 'Used More Than One Year', broken: 'Unbroken', description: "These are apple earphones with a lightning connector. Well used. Don't need them as I don't use an iPhone anymore."}, 
        {id: 2, name: 'Xbox Controller', img:'CLOUDINARY_IMAGE_LINK', location: 'location',
        type: 'Electronics', contact: { Phone: '1234567890' },
        used: 'Used More Than One Year', broken: 'Unbroken', description: "These are apple earphones with a lightning connector. Well used. Don't need them as I don't use an iPhone anymore."},
        {id: 3, name: 'Standing Fan', img:'CLOUDINARY_IMAGE_LINK', location: 'location',
        type: 'Electronics', contact: { Phone: '1234567890' },
        used: 'Used More Than One Year', broken: 'Unbroken', description: "These are apple earphones with a lightning connector. Well used. Don't need them as I don't use an iPhone anymore."},
        {id: 4, name: 'Apple Earphones', img:'CLOUDINARY_IMAGE_LINK', location: 'location',
        type: 'Electronics', contact: { Phone: '1234567890' },
        used: 'Used More Than One Year', broken: 'Unbroken', description: "These are apple earphones with a lightning connector. Well used. Don't need them as I don't use an iPhone anymore."}, 
        {id: 5, name: 'Xbox Controller', img:'CLOUDINARY_IMAGE_LINK', location: 'location',
        type: 'Electronics', contact: { Phone: '1234567890' },
        used: 'Used More Than One Year', broken: 'Unbroken', description: "These are apple earphones with a lightning connector. Well used. Don't need them as I don't use an iPhone anymore."}, 
    ])

    function getSingleItem (id) {
        return items.find(obj => obj.id == id)
    }

    function addItem (itemObject) {
        setItems([...items, itemObject]);
    }

    return {
        items,
        getSingleItem,
        addItem
    }
}
```

The context is provided globally within _app.js

```
import Layout from '../components/Layout'
import { ItemContextProvider } from '../components/ItemContext'
import '../styles/globals.css'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const getLayout = Component.getLayout || ((page) => page)
  return (
    <ItemContextProvider>
          {getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />)}
    </ItemContextProvider>
    )
}

export default MyApp
```

Then I use this context in my nested layout so that any pages with /browse can access the list of items, search through them, and filter them so that a list of filtered items can be rendered within the child component.

```
import { createContext, useState, useEffect, useReducer } from 'react'
import { useItems } from './ItemContext'
import Navbar from './Navbar'
import Sidebar from './Sidebar'
import browseStyle from '../styles/Browse.module.css'

export const FilterContext = createContext();

const NestedLayout = ({ children }) => {
    const { items } = useItems();

    const [currentItems, setCurrentItems] = useState(items)
    const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('')

    const [filters, setFilters] = useState(
        {used: { Unused: true, UsedLessThanOneMonth: true, UsedFewMonths: true, UsedMoreThanOneYear: true },
        broken: { Unbroken: true, PartiallyBroken: true, CompletelyBroken: true },
        type: { Electronics: true, Books: true, CDs: true, Household: true, Furniture: true, Other: true },
    });
     
    const [filteredItems, setFilteredItems] = useState(currentItems);

    function reducer (searchFilter, action) {
        switch (action.type) {
            case 'search':
                if (action.payload.searchTerm === ('')) {
                    // setSearchTerm('')
                    searchFilter = currentItems;
                } else {
                    // setSearchTerm(action.payload.searchTerm.toLowerCase());
                    searchFilter = currentItems.filter(item => item.name.toLowerCase().includes(action.payload.searchTerm.toLowerCase()))
                }
                return searchFilter;
            default:
                searchFilter = currentItems;
                return searchFilter    
        }
    }
  
    const [searchFilter, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, currentItems);
    
    function filterReducer (filterFilter, action) {
        switch (action.type) {
            case 'filter':
                filterFilter = currentItems.filter(item => getFilteredItems(item))
                return filterFilter;
            default: 
                filterFilter = currentItems;
                return filterFilter;
        }
    }

    const [filterFilter, dispatchFilter] = useReducer(filterReducer, currentItems);

    useEffect (() => {
        dispatchFilter({type: 'filter', payload: {filters: filters}})
    }, [filters])

    useEffect (() => {
        setFilteredItems( searchFilter.filter(element => filterFilter.includes(element)))
    },[searchFilter, filterFilter])

    useEffect (()=> {
        setCurrentItems(items)
        dispatchFilter({type: 'filter', payload: {filters: filters}})
        dispatch({ type: 'search', payload: { searchTerm: ''} })
    }, [items])

    function getFilteredItems(item) {
        const noWhiteSpaces = item.used.replace(/\s+/g, '');
        const itemProperties = [item.type, noWhiteSpaces, item.broken]
      
        const allKeys = Object.entries(filters).map(category => Object.keys(category[1]))
        const allKeysFlat = allKeys.flat();
        const allEntries = Object.entries(filters).map(category => Object.entries(category[1]))
        const allEntriesFlat = allEntries.flat()
        const finalObject = Object.fromEntries(allEntriesFlat)
        const filtered = allKeysFlat.filter(key => finalObject[key]);
      
        const found = itemProperties.every(r=> filtered.includes(r))

        return found;
    }


    return (
        <FilterContext.Provider value={filteredItems}>
            <main className={browseStyle.main}>
                <Navbar dispatch={dispatch}/>
                <div className={browseStyle.browse}>
                    <Sidebar filters={filters} setFilters={setFilters}/>
                        {children}
                </div> 
            </main>
        </FilterContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default NestedLayout
```

Currently the site works as expected when starting from the index page and proceeding to the browse page. The item list gets populated and items can be added successfully. However, if I attempt to enter the site through any page actively using the context (eg: http://localhost:3000/browse), I'm met with this error:

TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'items' of '(0 , *ItemContext__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1*_.useItems)(...)' as it is undefined.

I'm assuming it is because the page loads before the Context does while starting from the index gives the Context time to load before it is accessed. How would I go about addressing this error? Is my usage of the Context API fundamentally flawed?

Comment: check this part `const { items } = useItems();`

Comment: Try to destructure the `itemContext` value when you initialize your provider: `<ItemContext.Provider value={{...itemContext}}>`

Comment: @LucaPizzini Unfortunately I'm still getting the same error

Comment: @ABDULLOKHMUKHAMMADJONOV I understand that that line is responsible for the error, but I have no idea how to fix it. Any pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: It is not a named export, so `const items = useItems();`

Comment: @ABDULLOKHMUKHAMMADJONOV When I try that, the context is not identified by the child components at all (functions trying to map through the context such as .map or .filter throw errors stating that it is undefined). 

To reiterate, my current error only arises when I type localhost:3000/browse into the address bar. When I type localhost:3000, then click a button to navigate to localhost:3000/browse, I do not get the error, and the items are displayed as intended. But when I reload the browse page I get the error again.

Comment: @PriyankadeSilva Your `ItemContext` does not have an initial value set, so it defaults to `undefined`. On a page's first load the context value returned by `useItems()` will be `undefined` hence causing the error when you try to destructure it. You could declare `ItemContext` as `const ItemContext = createContext({ items: [] });` to fix it.